# ob_end_flush times out after calling ob_end_flush timing

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, fastcgi

I'm using WordPress 6.1.1 on the following spec (Nginx + PHP FPM):

```
nginx version: nginx/1.21.1
PHP 7.4.33
```

The following function keeps timing out after 5 minutes (sometimes it works after 6-7 minutes) when buffering 36MB (used ob_get_length() to measure it) which are reasonable for the WP plugin being used.

```
function wp_ob_end_flush_all() {
    $levels = ob_get_level();
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $levels; $i++ ) {
        ob_end_flush();
    }
}
```

I tried to turn off zlib.output_compression but it isn't the issue.

Also, I tried to disabling buffering

```
\remove_action('shutdown', 'wp_ob_end_flush_all', 1);
\add_action('shutdown', function() {
    header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
    $levels = \ob_get_level();
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $levels; $i++ ) {
        \ob_end_flush();
    }
}, 1);
```

It is still timing out and I have no clue.
Any ideas where would the bottle neck be?

**EDIT**

After increasing the max_execution_timeout to 600 it now loads after 6.2m, but that's a lot for 36 MB, that when gzipped are 902 KB. Something still doesn't make sense in the communication between PHPFpm-Nginx.

Comment: A 36MB web page is *extremely* large. It's possible you're seeing timeouts because your users' browsers slow down while ingesting the data from your buffers. Is it possible that one or more of those buffers is supposed to be cleaned (discarded) rather than flushed (sent to the browser)? All WordPress core code and most plugin code flushes or cleans the `ob_` buffers they create. The code construct you have here shouldn't be necessary in normal operation.  Maybe [edit] your question to tell us more about your situation?

Comment: @O.Jones yeah, it is extremely large but the problem is that it is not even going beyond the ob_end_flush() - it is stuck before it, which makes me think it is the FastCGI protocol between Nginx / PHP-FPM, the browser isn't receiving anything. 36 MB is large but not an impossible edge case, I have seen it working. It is a plugin that renders CSV entries inside the HTML to be used by jQuery.

Comment: Are you able to not use output buffering, and instead send directly?

Comment: @ChrisHaas yes, tried it via PHP and via Nginx (output_buffering = Off) but nothing. The HTML is rendered after 6 minutes (it is only 36MB) after increasing max_execution_timeout to 600.